# I hate Mondays!

Tags: code-golf, quine, date

You should a program in language X, which will only output its source code (i.e function as a quine) when it is not a monday. On monday it should output some string with a levehnstein distance of 4 from the source code. i.e if the code is aaaa on sunday it should output aaaa and on monday it could output ....aaaa or bbbb or cccc or ..aaaa.. etc

---

Read about Levehnstein difference here https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Levenshtein_distance

---

Rules

Your solution must be testable

No cheating quines, and any other standard loopholes allowed

Should your language "X" lack access to the date it may assume its a random date at the cost of 35 bytes

This is code golf and I will accept the shortest solution (in bytes) as winner

Comment: This is yet another [generalized quine challenge](http://meta.codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/8595/45941)...

Comment: Yes I was worried that it would be closed as such, but if the moderators would have wanted to close it as duplicate they would have by now.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

## Jolf, <s>19</s> <s>13</s> 9 bytes

```
?wfb+q~2q
```

[Try it online.](http://conorobrien-foxx.github.io/Jolf/)

Saved quite a few bytes thanks to Conor.

```
?wfb+q~2q

?wfb+q~2q
?          if
 wfb       the current weekday - 1 (which is 0 on Monday) is truthy
    +q~2   print the program's source code with 1000 appended to it
           else
        q  print the program's source code
```

Comment: It's only 1 byte longer than CJam so I wouldn't say this is _that_ long.

Comment: @Downgoat It should be at minimum 2 bytes shorter but there's a bug

Comment: For the condition, try `='MFf3`. For the extra four characters, try `*4S` (four newlines)

Comment: Ah. Good thing it's a Monday and not a Tuesday.

Comment: Does using a quine built-in not count as a cheating quine any more?

Comment: @MartinEnder I would consider it cheating, but it seems to be a respectable answer. Also I did not specifically warn againt apart from "reading the programs source or "standard loopholes"" I would be inclined to allow it, but what is the community consensus on this matter?

Comment: Usually to me "cheating quine" means reading the source code from the file on disk. Unfortunately there is no real community consensus on this; quines have always been kind of a murky area partially because there is no good definition of a "proper" quine

Comment: Hey, more golfing! replace `*4S` with `~2` and `='MFf3` with `wfb`.(I think, at least, on the last one.)

Comment: @CᴏɴᴏʀO'Bʀɪᴇɴ I get the `wfb` (I didn't know `fb` existed) but how does the `~2` work? Does it literally insert 1000 into the transpiled code?

Comment: Yes, it does. `~1` is 100, `~2` is 1000, `~3` is `10000`, `~4` is `10000`, and `~5` is `16`.

Comment: Right, I knew that. I just always assumed they were treated as variables and not inserted directly (meaning that it wouldn't have casted to string)

Comment: Currently the most [upvoted post on meta](http://meta.codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/4878/31625) about this suggests that a quine consist of data and code. I feel like it is hard to argue that this quine built-in uses code to take some data to generate the quine. It is of course up to the poster to decide, but I don't personally think that this is particularly in the spirit of quine challenges.

Answer (score 8):

## Javascript - <s>47</s> <s>45</s> <s>43</s> <s>42</s> <s>34</s> <s>32</s> 29 bytes

*8 bytes saved thanks to @Downgoat.*

*5 bytes saved thanks to @Dendrobium.*

```
f=_=>(Date()[0]!="M"&&"f=")+f
```

Comment: `!Date().search\`Mon\`` is shorter way to check if it is monday

Comment: @Downgoat cool, didn't know. how does ` work btw?

Comment: `Date()[0]=='M'` is even shorter

Comment: `\`` uses `Date().search` as a tag rather than a function. It'll still call it though but it'll pass some more properties. [You can read more here under "tagged template literals"](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals)

Comment: @Downgoat that's what i had before, but why don't i need to cast?

Comment: On Safari at least `Date()` returns a string. `new Date()` returns a date objcet rather than a string

Comment: @Downgoat oic, `new Date()` gives date object, `Date()` gives string. thanks

Comment: `f=_=>Date()[0]=="M"?1e3+f:"f="+f` for 32 bytes

Comment: @Dendrobium how does the `_` work? nice trick with `1e3` btw.

Comment: @Maltysen `_` is just a variable name that goes unused inside the function.

Comment: @Dendrobium cool.

Comment: Huh, `f=_=>(Date()[0]!="M"&&"f=")+f` for 29 bytes. When its Monday, the function returns `false_=>(Date()[0]!="F"&&"f=")+f` with the difference between `=` and `alse` being 4.

Comment: @Dendrobium haha nice!

Comment: If the challange was about fridays, you could check it with `Date()[0]<"G"`, saving one byte, but as far as I can see, you can’t make use of Unicode ordering here…

Comment: Why not `f=_=>Date()[0]!="M"&&"f="+f`?

Answer (score 5):

### CJam, <s>18</s> 17 bytes

```
{"_~"et7=({\}|}_~
```

[Test it here.](http://cjam.aditsu.net/#code=%7B%22_~%22et7%3D(%7B%5C%7D%7C%7D_~)

On Mondays, it prints:

```
_~{"_~"et7=({\}|}
```

Dennis found a 16-byte solution which will break in the year 10,000 though:

```
{"_~"et_7=1=<}_~
```

On Mondays, this prints

```
{"_~"et_7=1=<}_~2016
```

... or whatever the current year is.

Comment: `{et_7=1=<"_~"}_~` works for the next ~8000 years.

Comment: @Dennis haha, that's a neat idea.

Answer (score 3):

## Mathematica, 75 bytes

```
StringJoin[If[DayName[] == Monday, "0001", ""], ToString[#0, InputForm]] &
```

Anonymous function, takes no inputs and returns the output. Replace `Monday` with `Friday` (or whatever the current day is) to test.

Comment: i see lots of spaces

Comment: @Maltysen A byproduct of the quine mechanism

Comment: oh, lol ------------

Answer (score 3):

## [Vitsy](http://esolangs.org/wiki/Vitsy) + bash, <s>29</s> 26 bytes

```
'&"etad","M"-)[Y4\a]?rd3*Z

'                            Take a string of everything until hitting another '.
                             This will wrap around as it finds none.
 &                           Create a new stack and push the current stack over.
  "etad"                     Push the string "date" to the stack.
        ,                    Execute the current stack through shell.
         "M"-                Subtract the character "M" from the first item of the
                             current stack.
             )[    ]         If it is equal to zero, do the stuff in brackets.
               Y             Remove the current stack.
                4\a          Push the return character to the stack four times.
                    ?        Rotate over a stack (if there is none, stay put).
                     r       Reverse the stack.
                      d3*    Push the character ' to the stack.
                         Z   Print everything in the current stack.
```

This cannot be tried online as it accesses shell, however, feel free to test this with the downloadable interpreter found [here](https://github.com/VTCAKAVSMoACE/Vitsy).

Note that this is a variant of the standard quine, `'rd3*Z`.

Answer (score 3):

### Batch, 128 bytes

```
@set/am=%date:~3,2%,a=(14-m)/12,y=%date:~6%-a,d=(%date:~0,2%+y+y/4-y/100+y/400+(m+47)*18/7+a*3)%%7
@if %d%==1 echo @:
@type %0
```

Since Windows XP, `date` doesn't give you the day of the week, so I must directly calculate it from the date. The leap year adjustment wants March-based years so `a` is used as an adjusting factor. `(m+47)*18/7` is quicker than using a month-based lookup table.

Note that you need to invoke the file using its full name (e.g. `monday.bat`). The `echo @:` counts as a distance of 4 because of the extra CR/LF; I used `@:` because the result is still a syntactically valid batch script.

Comment: Date format is related to system setting

Answer (score 2):

## Java "Only" 2,897 bytes

Take a look at this monstrosity. Can someone help me test this on a monday, I cant figure out how to trick Java into thinking its monday.

```
import java.util.Calendar;public class Quine{public static void main(String[] args){char[] s={83,121,115,116,101,109,46,111,117,116,46,112,114,105,110,116,40,34,105,109,112,111,114,116,32,106,97,118,97,46,117,116,105,108,46,67,97,108,101,110,100,97,114,59,112,117,98,108,105,99,32,99,108,97,115,115,32,81,117,105,110,101,123,112,117,98,108,105,99,32,115,116,97,116,105,99,32,118,111,105,100,32,109,97,105,110,40,83,116,114,105,110,103,91,93,32,97,114,103,115,41,123,34,41,59,83,121,115,116,101,109,46,111,117,116,46,112,114,105,110,116,40,34,99,104,97,114,91,93,32,115,61,123,34,41,59,102,111,114,40,105,110,116,32,105,61,48,59,105,60,115,46,108,101,110,103,116,104,45,49,59,105,43,43,41,123,83,121,115,116,101,109,46,111,117,116,46,112,114,105,110,116,40,40,105,110,116,41,115,91,105,93,43,34,44,34,41,59,125,83,121,115,116,101,109,46,111,117,116,46,112,114,105,110,116,40,40,105,110,116,41,115,91,115,46,108,101,110,103,116,104,45,49,93,43,34,125,59,34,41,59,102,111,114,40,99,104,97,114,32,99,58,32,115,41,123,83,121,115,116,101,109,46,111,117,116,46,112,114,105,110,116,40,99,41,59,125,105,102,40,67,97,108,101,110,100,97,114,46,103,101,116,73,110,115,116,97,110,99,101,40,41,46,103,101,116,40,55,41,61,61,50,41,123,83,121,115,116,101,109,46,111,117,116,46,112,114,105,110,116,40,34,109,111,110,100,34,41,59,125,125,125,83,121,115,116,101,109,46,111,117,116,46,112,114,105,110,116,40,34,105,109,112,111,114,116,32,106,97,118,97,46,117,116,105,108,46,67,97,108,101,110,100,97,114,59,112,117,98,108,105,99,32,99,108,97,115,115,32,81,117,105,110,101,123,112,117,98,108,105,99,32,115,116,97,116,105,99,32,118,111,105,100,32,109,97,105,110,40,83,116,114,105,110,103,91,93,32,97,114,103,115,41,123,34,41,59,83,121,115,116,101,109,46,111,117,116,46,112,114,105,110,116,40,34,99,104,97,114,91,93,32,115,61,123,34,41,59,102,111,114,40,105,110,116,32,105,61,48,59,105,60,115,46,108,101,110,103,116,104,45,49,59,105,43,43,41,123,83,121,115,116,101,109,46,111,117,116,46,112,114,105,110,116,40,40,105,110,116,41,115,91,105,93,43,34,44,34,41,59,125,83,121,115,116,101,109,46,111,117,116,46,112,114,105,110,116,40,40,105,110,116,41,115,91,115,46,108,101,110,103,116,104,45,49,93,43,34,125,59,34,41,59,102,111,114,40,99,104,97,114,32,99,58,32,115,41,123,83,121,115,116,101,109,46,111,117,116,46,112,114,105,110,116,40,99,41,59,125,105,102,40,67,97,108,101,110,100,97,114,46,103,101,116,73,110,115,116,97,110,99,101,40,41,46,103,101,116,40,55,41,61,61,50,41,123,83,121,115,116,101,109,46,111,117,116,46,112,114,105,110,116,40,34,109,111,110,100,34,41,59,125,125,125};System.out.print("import java.util.Calendar;public class Quine{public static void main(String[] args){");System.out.print("char[] s={");for(int i=0;i<s.length-1;i++){System.out.print((int)s[i]+",");}System.out.print((int)s[s.length-1]+"};");for(char c: s){System.out.print(c);}if(Calendar.getInstance().get(7)==2){System.out.print("mond");}}}
```

Comment: What on earth is that char array?

Comment: Wtf 2,897 bytes

Comment: @Insane This is the only quine framework  i have come up with myself. I could rob a better quine framework from someone, but still I find my solution hilarious.

Comment: Okay now that looks really strange, I'm sure that can be golfed. At least by stripping some white space and renaming `args`

Comment: Yeah it could be golfed... for one I shouldn't use a char[] to store the code! Also I call the class Quine... Its golfed enough

Answer (score 2):

## GolfScript, <s>21</s> 20 + 35 = <s>56</s> 55 bytes (or <s>22 + 0 = 22</s> 20)

With randomizing, no input expected (following the rules completely):

```
{7rand 0=2*)".~"*}.~
```

Alternatively, date as input, in format like Javascript's `new Date().toString()` (bending the rules a little):

```
{\.,%"M"=2*)".~"*}.~
```

Each solution looks like this:

```
{somecode2*)".~"*}.~

{                }    create a block
                  .   duplicate it
                   ~  execute one copy
 somecode             push 1 if monday or 0 otherwise
         2*           multiply by 2 (2 if monday, 0 otherwise)
           )          add 1 (3 if monday, 1 otherwise)
            ".~"      the tail...
                *     ...copied 1 or 3 times and concatenated together
```

Now the stack looks like this:

```
.~  (or .~.~.~)
{somecode2*)".~"*}
```

... and is printed bottom to top.

The somecode part for random:

```
7rand 0=

7rand          select a random number from 0 to 6, let 0 be monday
      0=       check if equal to 0 (1 if monday, 0 otherwise)
```

The somecode part for input:

```
\.,%"M"=
\             we have the input first and the block on top, so we need to swap them
 .            duplicate the input
  ,           replace the second copy with its length
   %          get every (length)-th character starting from 0, effectively fetching first (M on mondays, something else otherwise)
    "M"=      check if equal to M (1 on mondays, 0 otherwise)
```

Comment: Good Answer! Welcome to Programming Puzzles and code Golf! While technically quines (and quine variants) should take no input, I do like both solutions to be there and they both seem well thought out!

Comment: @RohanJhunjhunwala Yes, they shouldn't take any input, I use it as an altervative for GolfScript's non-existent date builtin.

Answer (score 1):

### Java, 334 characters

```
import java.util.Calendar;interface Q{static void main(String[]a){String p="import java.util.Calendar;interface Q{static void main(String[]a){String p=%c%s%1$c;System.out.printf(p,34,p);if(Calendar.getInstance().get(7)==2)System.out.print(0<1);}}";System.out.printf(p,34,p);if(Calendar.getInstance().get(7)==2)System.out.print(0<1);}}
```

Based on @RohanJhunjhunwala 's solution, just using the quine method from over [here](http://rosettacode.org/wiki/Quine#Java). The difference of four comes by appending true if it's monday. I think it should be possible to shorten that a bit.

Answer (score 1):

## Reng v.5, noncompeting, 56 bytes

Version 5 brings to you object oriented programming!

```
"68¹65¹84¹69¹4&A3¹A1¹B6¹68¹97¹C1¹6Ó`1e4*{Xo}2[r*]rao! ;~
```

This is a standard quine. Simply, `"<code>rao! ;~` executes `<code>`, then outputs the programming, then exits.

`¹` is Manhattan addition, e.g., digit concatenation. This gives the char codes of `DATE`, then `4&` retrieves the date from the date module. (Equivalently, `"DATE"4&`.) This pushes a date object. (While it looks like it should be easily retrievable from the display in the stack, this is just how it prints in the stack display. It is unable to be manipulated.)

The next series provides another pseudo string, translating to `getDay`. Then, we get the property `getDay` of the date object on the stack using `6Ó`. We then execute it with `` ` ``. This provides JS's `getDay`. When it's `1`, it's monday. We check for equality with `1` using `1e`, then multiply by four. `{Xo}` pushes a code block that prints (`o`) char 33 (`X`), or `!`. `2[r` creates a new stack with the top two items in reverse order. Then, we repeat (`*`) the code block 4 times (when monday) or 0 times (any other day). On monday, it prints 4 `!`s. Otherwise, it prints nothing. Then the string captured by wraparound is printed, and we have the rest of our source.

Output on monday:

```
!!!!68¹65¹84¹69¹4&A3¹A1¹B6¹68¹97¹C1¹6Ó`1e4*{Xo}2[r*]rao! ;~
```

On other days:

```
68¹65¹84¹69¹4&A3¹A1¹B6¹68¹97¹C1¹6Ó`1e4*{Xo}2[r*]rao! ;~
```